Abstract Base Class property setter absence not preventing Class instantiation
I'm trying to get abstract properties to work, enforcing property getter & setter definitions in downstream classes.
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class BaseABC(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def x(self):
        pass

    @x.setter
    @abstractmethod
    def x(self, value):
        pass


class MyClass(BaseABC):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._x = value
    
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    # @x.setter
    # def x(self, val):
    #     self._x = val


obj = MyClass(10)
print(obj.x)
obj.x = 20
print(obj.x)

Having read the documentation it seems to indicate the above should trigger a TypeError, when the class is being build, but it only triggers an AttributeError once the attribute is being set.
Why does the absent setter, explicitly defined in BaseABC through an @abstractmethod, not trigger the expected TypeError?
How does one ensure a setter is required in the daughter class?

property alone replaces the abstract setter with None, which is "good enough" as far as ABC is concerned.

TL;DR property doesn't just override the getter; it overrides the setter with None as well.

In MyClass, property creates a brand new property with the given getter and no setter; it doesn't simply override the getter of the inherited property. The definition of MyClass.x is equivalent to
def x_getter(self):
     return self._x

x = property(x_getter, None)

and that None as a setter is "good enough" as far as ABC is concerned with respect to overriding the abstract setter.
To "inherit" the abstract setter as well, use
class MyClass(BaseABC):

    @BaseABC.x.getter
    def x(self):
        return self._x

This creates a new property not from scratch, but from the existing BaseABC.x property, using its (abstract) setter but a new getter (just like x.setter before created a new property using the old getter but a new setter).
To make MyClass instantiable, you still need to provide a concrete setter using x.setter.

Unfortunately, nothing forces you to to use BaseABC.x.getter in place of property. ABC only cares that x gets set to something appropriate. This is a general problem with ABC, not properties in particular. There is only so much you can do at the library level; abstract base classes are not a feature of Python itself.

The don't want to make MyClass instantiable. They expect instantiation to fail because the setter is missing. But it's not failing.

That's fine; the definition of MyClass shown isn't instantiable, as it's missing a concrete setter.

The question says "but it only triggers an AttributeError once the attribute is being set." It's not getting an error when they do obj = MyClass(10)

Yes, their class is not abstract, because it doesn't have an abstract setter: it has no setter at all. My definition does have an abstract setter, because it still has the same setter defined by BaseABC.

But the setter in BaseABC has @abstractmethod, which is supposed to make it abstract and prevent instantiation of a subclass that doesn't override it.

I'm not sure about the exact details, but MyClass.__abstractmethods__ still contains 'x' as long as you haven't overriden the setter with either a concrete function or None.

Your answer does cause an error during instantiation. But I think the whole point is to catch cases where you forget to implement something in the subclass, so requiring something be explicitly added to trigger the error is defeating the purpose.

Yes, after reading the other answer (and unfairly downvoting it initially), I see that angle now.

Thank you both for the discussion, I feel like I learned a lot from it. My intention was indeed to make it harder for subclasses to have an absent setter implementation, it is interesting to read not only that but why this wouldn't work here.

There is no way to enforce what you're looking for.
Fundamentally, overriding doesn't happen at a fine enough level of granularity for this. When you override a property, you override the whole property, getter, setter, deleter, and all. Python doesn't even care if you override it with another property - you could override it with the string "banana".
All the ABC machinery enforces is that subclasses have to override your abstract property with something concrete, for the subclass to be concrete. It doesn't care whether that something is a read-write property, or a property at all - "banana" would be considered fine.
